# where can I download xsltproc that is compatible with ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu-drivers

Where can I download xsltproc that is compatible with Ubuntu 12.04? I need this tool to install my Epson perfection V500 photo scanner.

Answer (score 8):

XSLTProc for 12.04 is (or should be) in Software Center, or install it by typing `sudo apt-get install xsltproc`.

Answer (score 1):

xsltproc for 12.04 is not in main repository now. So cannot install with `apt-get` command.

you can download the .deb file from [www.ubuntuupdates.org](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/precise/main/base/xsltproc) and install with following command:

```
sudo dpkg -i [Deb file]
```

Comment: Fair enough. From [this](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/i386/xsltproc) I was led to believe it was in the main repo.